# FIXED: How to center the middle item of a Flex that already centered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

#### Middle item can't center

[image: Web view]

#### Code

```js
<Flex position="relative" p={2} display={{base: "none", md: "flex"}} backgroundColor="#022e57" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
    <Box >
        {userData ? <UserData props={userData}/> : <Heading ml={4} color="white">Noobs</Heading>}
    </Box>
    <Box>
        <Button colorScheme="grey">
            Home
        </Button>
        <Button colorScheme="grey">
            Lịch sử
        </Button>
        <Button colorScheme="grey">
            Chúng tôi
        </Button>
    </Box>
    <Box mr="3rem">
        {userData ? 
            <Button colorScheme="red" onClick={LogOut}> 
                Thoát 
            </Button> : 
            <Link href="http://localhost:3001/api/auth/discord" _hover={null}>
                <Button colorScheme="green">
                    Đăng nhập
                </Button>
            </Link>
        }
    </Box>
</Flex>
```

#### Question

How I can center the `<Box>` with **3 Buttons** to middle, cause the design looks kinda trash

Comment: set <Flex> position relative then  <UserData /> and <Button CTA/> absolute to left and right zero of your <Flex>. Then set  <Flex> justifyContent: "center" and alignItems="center"

Comment: Is the Flex and Box components are from any component Library ?

Comment: @Shyam they are from chakra-ui

Comment: How did you fix this in the end?